# React invalid or unexpexted token

Tags: reactjs

This is a strange problem. I set up a react project in ubuntu 20.4. Then i have done some work and push it to a git repo. Then i shut down my laptop. The next day when i tried to start the project with npm start it shows the error. But i i deleted the project folder and then clone the project via the git repo, it works fine. Then next day when i tried to run the project it shoes the same error, and then repeating the same procedure the project runs. What is the reason of this occurance, i could not find any solution.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNP4K.png)

Comment: рlease show a full log of the error

Comment: looking at the screenshot provided, it's most likely an error with npm install, before `npm start` install all the dependencies via `npm install`

Comment: @vishwasmeshram i run the npm install command before npm start

Comment: @DaniilLoban did you mean .log file??

Comment: @HasnainNisan, I meant what gets to the console after launch

Comment: @DaniilLoban it would not launch, npm start displays error in the screenshot. But after cloning from the git it runs without any error in the console

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see an error in the identifier.js file but there in the first line "use strict"; those. most likely a problem with the hard drive. I would advise you to test it for complete peace of mind, probably sometimes the files are not saved correctly

For example, I changed my file by adding a sad smiley, it could be anything that is outside the scope of the syntax, in your case it was non-printable characters.

[image]